# Phonegap 1.0 and iOS 4.3

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, ios4

i started developing an hybrid app using phone gap and jquery. while the
android app is working quite fine, except some performance and usability issues according 
effects - like page transitions-, i tried to "port" this app to an iPod touch running iOS 4.3!

calling the camera, the photo library or accessing the filesystem stopped working, and actually i experienced that even the listener for checking if the device got ready stopped working.

well what happened? actually the hooks in the window-object for accessing the filesystem or other features are not available on iOS.

.... ???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgraded your version of PhoneGap and are still using a project that was made before you upgraded, then you should create a new PhoneGap project in Xcode and put your `www` folder in the new project. This worked for me.

Comment: hi! well i reinstalled the phone gap and created a new project ..
but now the app starts and the suddenly crashes in 

AppDelegate.m there a SIGABRT has been thrown!

so the ondeviceready event gets invoked but suddenly the crash happens!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are linking to the correct `phonegap.js` file. Although they are all titled the same, each OS has a different version. Go into the unzipped directory  you downloaded from phonegap's site and make sure you're using the iOS version of `phonegap.js`.